# How to remove WooCommerce Payments wc-blocks-checkout-style-css from footer

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have the following WooCommerce Payments stylesheet being loaded in my  tag and have not been able to find out how to remove it:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wc-blocks-checkout-style-css'  href='https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-payments/dist/upe-blocks-checkout.css?ver=1.0' media='all' />
```

(I only use WooCommerce on certain pages so therefore do not need all of the files to be loaded on most pages)  I checked with WooCommerce and was not able to get answers.

I removed the stylesheet from loading in the header successfully within the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook using:

```
wp_dequeue_style('wc-blocks-checkout-style');
```

but the following line still appears in the footer and loads the same CSS file:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wc-blocks-checkout-style-css'  href='https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-payments/dist/upe-blocks-checkout.css?ver=1.0' media='all' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for this answer too.
The stylesheet is enqueued by this file of the plugin:
woocommerce-payments/includes/class-wc-payments-upe-blocks-payment-method.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Class WC_Payments_Blocks_Payment_Method
 *
 * @package WooCommerce\Payments
 */

/**
 * The payment method, which allows the gateway to work with WooCommerce Blocks.
 */
class WC_Payments_UPE_Blocks_Payment_Method extends WC_Payments_Blocks_Payment_Method {
    /**
     * Defines all scripts, necessary for the payment method.
     *
     * @return string[] A list of script handles.
     */
    public function get_payment_method_script_handles() {
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'wc-blocks-checkout-style',
            plugins_url( 'dist/upe-blocks-checkout.css', WCPAY_PLUGIN_FILE ),
            [],
            '1.0'
        );

        wp_register_script(
            'stripe',
            'https://js.stripe.com/v3/',
            [],
            '3.0',
            true
        );

        wp_register_script(
            'WCPAY_BLOCKS_CHECKOUT',
            plugins_url( 'dist/upe-blocks-checkout.js', WCPAY_PLUGIN_FILE ),
            [ 'stripe' ],
            '1.0.1',
            true
        );
        wp_set_script_translations( 'WCPAY_BLOCKS_CHECKOUT', 'woocommerce-payments' );

        return [ 'WCPAY_BLOCKS_CHECKOUT' ];
    }
}
```